# How can I return a CSV string from PL/SQL table type in Oracle

Tags: string, oracle, types, plsql, collect

I have defined a table type PL/SQL variable and added some data there.

```
create or replace type varTableType as table of varchar2(32767);
my_table varTableType := varTableType()
...
my_table := some_function();
```

Now I have this `my_table` table type variable with several thousands of records.
I have to select only those records ending with specific character, say **'a'** and get results in a comma separated string.
I think that COLLECT function could do this, but I do not understand exactly how.
I am using Oracle 10g.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without getting into the question- why are you using a table type and not a table (or temporary table), you can do it like this:

```
declare
  my_table varTableType;
  i varchar2(32767);
begin
  my_table := new
              varTableType('bbbb', 'ccca', 'ddda', 'eee', 'fffa', 'gggg');

  select trim(xmlagg(xmlelement(e, column_value || ','))
              .extract('//text()'))
    into i
    from table(my_table)
   where column_value like '%a';

  dbms_output.put_line(i);

end;
```

There are more ways to concat rows- [WM_CONCAT](http://psoug.org/definition/WM_CONCAT.htm) (if enabled) or [LISTAGG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions087.htm) (since 11g R2) but the basic idea of

```
select column_value 
from table(my_table) 
where column_value like '%a';
```

stays

---

There is another way without sql:

```
declare
  my_table varTableType;
  i varchar2(32767);
begin
  my_table := new
              varTableType('bbbb', 'ccca', 'ddda', 'eee', 'fffa', 'gggg');

  FOR j IN my_table.first .. my_table.last LOOP

     IF my_table(j) like '%a' THEN
        i := i || my_table(j);
     END IF;

  END LOOP;

  dbms_output.put_line(i);

end;
```

Comment: Thank you, your examples covered my needs perfectly. Somehow I was lost and thought that the required solution would be more complex.

Answer (score 1):

See this [blog post by Tim Hall](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php) for a number of ways to do this, depending on Oracle version.